# Add segment number by batch

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

All,

Looking to add a new column in a df that has an segment number incremented in batches.  An example of the output would be something like this where the segment number increments with batches of 3 records:

```
Index   Animal  Segment
0       Dog     1
1       Cat     1
2       Cat     1
3       Bear    2
4       Bird    2
5       Dog     2
6       Dog     3
7       Dog     3
8       Cat     3
9       Bear    4
10      Bear    4
11      Lion    4
12      Dog     5
13      Lion    5
14      Cat     5
```

Not sure on the best way to achieve this in Pandas.  I know in regular python going line by line I would for loop and increment I, but have no idea how to do this in Pandas.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do:

```
df['Segment'] = np.arange(len(df))//3 + 1

Index   Animal  Segment
0       Dog     1
1       Cat     1
2       Cat     1
3       Bear    2
4       Bird    2
5       Dog     2
6       Dog     3
7       Dog     3
8       Cat     3
9       Bear    4
10      Bear    4
11      Lion    4
12      Dog     5
13      Lion    5
14      Cat     5
```

**Explanation**:

`np.arange(len(df))` creates a sequence of length `len(df)`, and with `//3` you are taking the floor division of its elements by 3, and by adding 1 to it you get the desired output.

Comment: you have beaten me with few secs :) with same answer.

Comment: Added a new solution using basic df stuff now :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
df['Segment']=df.index // 3 + 1
df
```

Comment: Don't forget to take the floor division though :-)